# Move child of shadow dom with slots out of the web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, slot

I'm trying to move a child of a shadow dom of a web component outside it, and has been able to do it if that child has not slots inside.

Let me ilustrate with an example. I have the following 2 web components:

```js
customElements.define('a-child', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <slot></slot>
        `
    }
})

customElements.define('a-parent', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <slot name="outside"></slot>
            <a-child id=child>
                <div>
                    <slot name="inside"></slot>
              </div>
            </a-child>
        `
    }
    
    move() {
        const child = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('child')
        document.body.append(child)
    }
})
```

And if I have the following HTML, I get what I want: even when slot `inside` is inside the `a-child` component in the Shadow DOM from `a-parent`, it shows up correctly.

```html
<a-parent id="parent">
    <div slot="outside">outside</div>
    <div slot="inside">inside</div>
</a-parent>
```

If I run the method `move` from element with Id `parent`, the `a-child` element is moved to the body and I was expecting to see the div with text `inside` in the body, but it doesn't happen. It seems that the slots only work when they are inside their web component.

My question is, is it possible to move a child of a Shadow DOM containing slots, outside of its web component parent?

Comment: ``<slot>`` elements only have a meaning **inside** shadowDOM, just like ``<li>`` elements only have a meaning inside a ``<ul>``, and ``<td>`` only do something inside a ``<table>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Slots only work when they are inside their enclosing Web Components. In other words, the slots should be physically present in the DOM tree under the web component node.

Further, it is possible to move the children of Shadow DOM but if they contain slots, then it won't work. It will just fail silently without any errors.

That is one of the reasons why it is annoying. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56269880/5723098) for similar question. Also, this [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/justinfagnani/status/1457737165945774081) contains some more related information. In summary, you need to move slot elements outside the component for achieving perfect stacking context for creating components like dialogs, menus, drop-downs, etc.

Comment: Tbh, in almost 5 years of web component development as my main focus, I not once found a decent use-case for slots.

Comment: Tbh, in my 4 years of Web Component development I have used ``<slot>`` several times in projects, remarkably always in use cases where I needed to place lightDOM content in a shadowDOM container and leave the styling to the Component user.

Comment: I have a mixed feelings about slots. They are useful as long as I am purely treating them for serving the needs of DOM placeholder. But that's it. Their use beyond that is doubtful. As a library user, the `slots` or `children` model provided by Vue and React are far more flexible because you are not dealing with DOM but its representation that can be augmented/enhanced before final rendering to DOM. If I have to use some library to achieve same with Web Components, then it is problematic situation no matter how much I romanticize the idea of web components.

Comment: I have found one nice use case for slots - rearranging DOM nodes without having to disconnect / reconnect them. Sometimes its nice to be able to rearrange custom elements without triggering their constructors / lifecycle callbacks, and to do that i just put slots wherever the element might need to go and then re-slot the element. I konw certain CSS view apis can let you re-order nodes purely via css but this method has a lot less limitations